# Remove event.preventDefault() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am little stuck , I have `username` input field; if the field is empty then submit button wont work, else if there is some value in the field the submit button will work.

html

```
<input type="username" class="comn_cstm_uname">
<input type="submit" class="submtidjq" value ="submit">
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){
        if(!$(".comn_cstm_uname").val()){
            alert("hello"); 
            $(".submtidjq").on('click', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        } else {
            $('.submtidjq').unbind('click');
        }
    }, 5000);

</script>
```

the code is working up to `event.preventDefault()`, but when we fill some value in the `username` field the submit button wont work it still stops.

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all. Provided your inputs are part of a `<form>`, this works as expected ~ https://jsfiddle.net/qgzda8p5/

Comment: @Phil so what should i do now

Comment: Create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I would approach this differently by disabling the submit button and only re-enabling it within an _input_ event handler if there is text entered, eg `const btn = $(".submtidjq").prop("disabled", true); $(".comn_cstm_uname").on("input", e => btn.prop("disabled", e.target.value.trim().length > 0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are complicating your code logic as well as not providing full detail (i.e. you want to submit form when data is fill otherwise stop form submission)

Do like below:

```js
$('.submtidjq').click(function() {
  if ($.trim($(".comn_cstm_uname").val()) == '') { // use trim to prevent spaces submission
    alert("empty value");
    return false;
  }
});

//Or you can do like this as well

/*$('.submtidjq').click(function(event) {
  if ($.trim($(".comn_cstm_uname").val()) == '') {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("empty value");
  }
});*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="username" class="comn_cstm_uname">
  <input type="submit" class="submtidjq" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: i got your approch at the comment section and it worked thanks man

Answer (score 2):

it will not work because your input not inside `<form>` and you don't need `setInterval`

```js
$(".submtidjq").on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(".comn_cstm_uname").val()) {
  event.preventDefault();
    alert("hello");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="GET">
  <input type="username" class="comn_cstm_uname">
  <input type="submit" class="submtidjq" value="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it will help.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inputButton').prop( "disabled", true );
      $(".inputField").on('keyup', function(){
        if($(this).val().length > 0){
           $('.inputButton').prop( "disabled", false );
        }else{
        $('.inputButton').prop( "disabled", true );
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <input type="text" class="inputField" />
    <input type="button" class="inputButton" value="Submit"/>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```